# Adding items to ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter

I'm trying to add items to my list by clicking a button.  Each list item contains a 'TextView' which is supposed to be set to the value obtained from an EditText.  The first item is added correctly however, when I add another item to the list, the `TextView` of the previous list item is set to the new value.  So the result is having two (or however many you add) identical list items.

I can see why this happens in my code, but I don't know how to change it so it works correctly.

I am using a custom adapter for the `ListView`, called 'TimetableListAdapter'.  The data to be added to each list item comes from a 'DialogFragment' (not shown here as that data passing/transferring works fine)

```
    public class ScreenSlidePagerFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, AddLessonDialog.onSubmitListener {

        ViewGroup rootView;
        Button btn_addLesson;
        ListView lv_viewDay;
        TimetableListAdapter la_listAdapt;
        String[] lessonData;

        public ScreenSlidePagerFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_timetable_page, container, false);

            btn_addLesson = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_addLesson);
            btn_addLesson.setOnClickListener(this);

            lv_viewDay = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_viewDay);
            la_listAdapt = new TimetableListAdapter(getActivity());
            lv_viewDay.setAdapter(la_listAdapt);

            return rootView;
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {

                case R.id.btn_addLesson:

                  // Shows DialogFragment where data is input 

                    break;
            }
        }

        public class TimetableListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            private ArrayList<String[]> mDayList;

            Context mContext;

            public TimetableListAdapter(Context context) {

                mContext = context;
                mDayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();

            }


            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mDayList.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {

                return mDayList.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {

                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                if (null == convertView) {

                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                            R.layout.lesson_item, null);

                }

                    TextView tv_subjectField = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subjectField);
                    tv_subjectField.setText(lessonData[0]);

                    return convertView;
                }

            public void addLesson(int position, String subject, String teacher, String room, String period) {

                lessonData = new String[4]; 
                lessonData[0] = subject;

                mDayList.add(position, lessonData);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }


        @Override
        public void setOnSubmitListener(View v, String subject, String teacher, String room, String period, int position) {

            switch (v.getId()) {


                case R.id.btn_setLesson: // This is a button on the DialogFragment

// The data is passed through from the DialogFragment fine
                    la_listAdapt.addLesson(position, subject, teacher, room, period);

                    break;

            }
            }

        }
```

As you can see from my code, I'm trying to set the data in a list item to that passed through from the DialogFragment which is stored in a `String[]` at `addLesson()`.

Comment: `mDayList.add(position, lessonData);`. Why do you need a position parameter? Why not just add()?

Comment: @greenapps  I might want to add an item to somewhere else in the list rather than always at the top or bottom.  This is supposed (I think) allow me to add an item at any position I want. I did remove it to see if it made a difference and it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `getView` method of adapter, replace:

```
tv_subjectField.setText(lessonData[0]);
```

With:

```
tv_subjectField.setText(mDayList.get(position));
```

Comment: That doesn't set the TextView to the value that I want which is in lessonData.  And `mDayList.getPosition()` is not a String.

Comment: Then why are you not telling that it is a string array? `tv_subjectField.setText(mDayList.get(position)[0]);`

Comment: Thanks! @greenapps I should have checked for that.